# Command-line dialog tool for Windows

Tags: windows, shell, scripting, console, cdialog

I need a dialog tool similar to cdialog (or whiptail), but one that will work on Windows.

I have MinGW and compiling something from source is no problem, but both cdialog and whiptail, the only ones that I know of, contain code that is UNIX-specific, and so they will not compile on Windows.

Are there any alternatives that I can use? I'd rather not have to figure out and replace the platform-specific code myself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I remember the E Text Editor using [wxCocoaDialog](http://code.google.com/p/wxcocoadialog/) for that purpose:

> wxCocoaDialog is a multi-platform port of the CocoaDialog application for OS X, that allows the use of common GUI controls such as file selectors, text input, progress bars, yes/no confirmations and more with a command-line application. It is ideal for use in shell and Perl scripts (or Ruby, or Python, or... etc).

Comment: Very useful find, thanks a lot! If no better answer comes along, I will accept this one.

Answer (score 5):

There is a [port of dialog](http://andrear.altervista.org/home/cdialog.php) for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at Cygwin (http://www.cygwin.com/) rather than MinGW? Cygwin provides a very Unix/Linux like environment, to the extent that most Unix programs can be built without change. Depending on what you want to do with the results, though, Cygwin's licensing may be an issue.